# Going from a property List to a property Detail page to display details of selected property 404 not found

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using `httpClient` to retrieve data from a local `json` file. Everything is working fine in the `propertylist`. When i click a property, i want to go to a new page, and show the details of the selected property. I have watched countless videos, and read many guides but i just can't seem to fathom it out.

I believe its to do with routing, activated route and parameters. I have created the pages, service, imported the `router` and `activatedrouter`, and injected my service, and setup the `:id` path in the routing module.

Start of the JSON

```
{
    "property": [
        {
            "propertyID": "101552000007",
            "branchID": "1",
            "clientName": "Demo",
            "branchName": "Br",
            "department": "Sales",
            "referenceNumber": "10006",
            "addressName": "",
            "addressNumber": "87",
            "addressStreet": "Hackney Road",
            "address2": "",
            "address3": "London",
            "address4": "",
            "addressPostcode": "E2 8PP",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
        }
    ]
```

For-Sale page

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let property of propertyList.property; let i=index" size="6">


<ion-card  [routerLink]="['/read-post',property.propertyID]">
```

Service

```
getProperty(propertyID): Observable<IProperties[]> {
        return this.http.get<IProperties[]>('/assets/data/xx.json/' + propertyID);
}
```

read-post page

```
    ngOnInit() {
        let propertyID = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.saleService.getProperty(propertyID).subscribe((property) => {
            console.log(property);
        });
    }
```

app-routing

```
{ path: 'read-post/:id', loadChildren: './read-post/read-post.module#ReadPostPageModule' },
```

When i click a property in the for-sale page, it navigates to "http://localhost:8100/read-post/101552000015" (which is the propertyID in the json)

Console log

```
GET http://localhost:8100/assets/data/xx.json/101552000015 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameter to the `json` file which is not right, instead read the `json` file and then filter the data to get the required property.

Check the below code based on the JSON data you posted in the question.

Change `getProperty()` and `ngOnInit()` method as below:

```
    getProperty(): Observable<IProperties[]> {
            return this.http.get<IProperties[]>('/assets/data/xx.json/');
    }


    ngOnInit() {
            let propertyID = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
            this.saleService.getProperty().subscribe( data => {
                if(Boolean(data) && Boolean(data.property)){
                    let requiredValue = data.property.filter(ele => ele.propertyID === propertyID)[0];
                    console.log(requiredValue);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Amazing thankyou. I had followed a Youtube video to the letter except with my own json data so was a bit baffled. Could you possibly point me in the right direction as to what documentation i should be reading for this? As some of the code there i don't even understand if im honest.

Also, apologies for asking another question but how would i display the data in the html file? Would i still use string interpolation?
many thanks again